# Data frame Type error ' str' object in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The below code tries connects to ms sql db one by one using sql_connect() function, add new column to df (db number, db type)

The connectivity works, but I get error

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df_db = pd.DataFrame()
db_num = [30, 33, 39]
db_type = ['ms', 'ms', 'ms']
sql  = ['sql_connect_30()', 'sql_connect_33()', 'sql_connect_39()']
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
    print(db_num[i])
    print(db_type[i])
    print(sql[i])
    df_db = sql[i]
    df_db['db_num'] = db_num[i]
    df_db['db_type'] = db_type[i]
    df_db = pd.concat([df, df_db], axis = 0)
```

Error

```
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-a2c294742ba6>", line 12, in <cell line: 6>
    df_db['db_num'] = db_num[i]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I could do it by below method, but i want to try & learn with loop

```
df_30 = sql_connect_30()
df_33 = sql_connect_33()
df_39 = sql_connect_39()
df_30['db_num'] = 30
df_30['db_type'] = 'ms'
df_33['db_num'] = 33
df_33['db_type'] = 'ms'
df_39['db_num'] = 39
df_39['db_type'] = 'ms'
df_db = pd.concat([df_30, df_33, df_39], axis = 0)
del df_30, df_33, df_39
```

Could you guide on this or suggest efficient way

Comment: You assign a string to `df_db` and then try to use it as a pandas DataFrame. Try to remove the string delimiters in `sql=['sql_connect_30()', 'sql_connect_33()', 'sql_connect_39()']`, then it should work.

Comment: is it necessary to assign df and df_db to pd.DataFrame() at the beginning or is there any other way

Comment: `df_db` you don't have to initialize, `df` you have to - otherwise it is unclear where you would append to.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I think your code would be quite a bit cleaner as follows:

```
funcs = [sq_connect_30, sq_connect_33, sq_connect_39]
db_nums = [30, 33, 39]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
    df_sub = func()
    df_sub["db_num"] = db_nums[i]
    df_sub["db_type"] = "ms"
    df = pd.concat([df, df_sub], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: '-' in ignore index removed. but this error comes in this code NameError: name 'db_sub' is not defined

Comment: yeah, sorry - that was a typo, I wrote it directly in the answer - it's updated now.. Also, the `concat` method is now preferred to `append`.